# Creating a bat file to run raspberry pi commands on windows

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

I am trying to set up a simple `.bat` file to help non-tech people execute scripts by just selecting a file on the desktop. I installed Putty, and can manually SSH into the Raspberry Pi computers and run commands, but I can't teach that process to the employees.

I would like to create a simple `.bat` file that runs the following commands:

```
ssh pi@192.168.1.xxx 
<enter password>: 'xxx'
sudo reboot
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[Download Plink](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html)

I moved it AND Putty to *C:/Windows/system32* instead of changing PATH. This doesn't seem necessary, as the next step will automatically locate the file and change the path.

On your desktop, right-click, select *New*, and then *Shortcut*. In the shortcut path, enter the following (replacing '**xxx**' with the actual address):

`plink -ssh username@192.16.1.xxx -pw raspberry sudo reboot`

If you recheck the shortcut again, it should automatically change the path to execute Plink.